# Bootstrap 4 Column without Masonry method

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Im working on a bootstrap 4 column layout.

Below is my code

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">Section 1</div>
    <div class="col-6"> Section 2 Content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea animi, vero et ratione asperiores cumque aspernatur. Laudantium dolorum odit culpa maxime officiis aperiam necessitatibus enim eveniet, reprehenderit deserunt molestias in. </div>
    <div class="col-6"> Section 3</div>
    <div class="col-6"> Section 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can See There are four sections, separated using col-6, i want to make the section 3 to go to below of the section 1 content. I know there is masonry layout for this but is this possible to achieve this without that?

Kindly help because in responsive, i wanted the section 2 below the section 1 but in normal mode this layout is what i needed. i dont want to use the same code two times by hiding and showing

Comment: If  .row class is set as flex, you can use the property: order on its childs

Comment: You need to tweak some of the code to get the custom output that you are looking for. Here us my code. jsfiddle.net/rakeshnayak/g30rk5me/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tweak some of the code to get the custom output that you are looking for.

```css
.row{
  display:block;
}
.col-6{
  float:left;
}
.float-right{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">Section 1</div>
    <div class="col-6 float-right"> Section 2 Content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea animi, vero et ratione asperiores cumque aspernatur. Laudantium dolorum odit culpa maxime officiis aperiam necessitatibus enim eveniet, reprehenderit deserunt molestias in. </div>
    <div class="col-6"> Section 3</div>
    <div class="col-6"> Section 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `order-*` class in Bootstrap, You need to use [that](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#order-classes) . Please check below code.

> Use .order- classes for controlling the visual order of your content. These classes are responsive, so you can set the order by breakpoint (e.g., .order-1.order-md-2). Includes support for 1 through 12 across all five grid tiers.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 order-1">Section 1</div>
    <div class="col-6 order-3"> Section 2 Content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea animi, vero et ratione asperiores cumque aspernatur. Laudantium dolorum odit culpa maxime officiis aperiam necessitatibus enim eveniet, reprehenderit deserunt molestias in. </div>
    <div class="col-6 order-2"> Section 3</div>
    <div class="col-6 order-4"> Section 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please write the cntent sin one section inside a col-6 and other section inside the other col-6

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6">
           <p>section 1</p>
           <p>Section 3 Content.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="col-6">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea animi, vero et ratione asperiores cumque aspernatur. Laudantium dolorum odit culpa maxime officiis aperiam necessitatibus enim eveniet, reprehenderit deserunt molestias in.</p>
           <p>Section 4 Content.</p>
         </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, i want to show section 2 to below the section 1 on responsive so that your solution is not applicable.